# Why is "sic semper erat, et sic semper erit" translated this way?

Tags: translation-explanation

> This is what it always was and will always be

Where is the *thus* meaning in here from the word *sic*? And the word *this* is not written.

I've always wondered how these translations are made since I tried translating it (as a rookie) and got something along the lines of

> Thus it always was and thus it always will be.

Source:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Translation generally isn't a one-to-one mapping between Latin words and English words. While *sīc* is often glossed as "thus", you might also translate it as "like this", or "in this way", or "in this sort of condition", or "accordingly", or "as you see".

*Sīc erat* means something like "it was like this" or "it was this sort of way", so I would say "this is what it was" (or perhaps "this is how it was") is a reasonable translation.

Comment: More pointedly, "thus it always was" and "this is always what it always was" *mean* the same thing.

Comment: I found out that the artist is South African. Perhaps that explains the wording "This is what it always was," whereas I, an American, expect "This is how it always was."

Answer (score -1):

I am no scholar of Latin, but I am fluent in Spanish and English. Spanish is a variant of ancient Latin, which I believe died out because only Roman Catholic priests were permitted to learn it and speak it. The Catholic Church prohibited laypersons from learning Latin or speaking Latin. Hence it was never passed down through generations.

If you were to translate from Latin to Spanish, the phrase would read: “Si siempre era, entonces siempre será”

Translate this Spanish phrase into English and you now have this: “If it always was, then it will always be.”

Translating from Latin to Spanish and then from Spanish to English reduces speculation of how it would have read in English because Spanish to English is more straight forward, and Latin translates into Spanish quite easily because the words are similarly spelled and phonetically similar. This is not scientific but I am fluent in Spanish and English. Hope this helps.

Comment: *Sic* and *si* are not the same word.

Comment: Right, *Sic semper erat = Siempre ha sido así.*